# Programmatically get report table type from a Crystal Reports .rpt file usng C#

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, report

I want to get the table type from crystal report (.rpt) file using C#.
In Crystal Report, Databaseà Set Database Location à Expand the Name of the database object, properties, then Table Name and Table Type get appear.
I can get the Table Name, solution is given with this url [Programmatically get report tables from a Crystal Reports .rpt file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10235474/programmatically-get-report-tables-from-a-crystal-reports-rpt-file)

Is it possible to get the Table type from .rpt file?

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure that you can adapt the code from RptToXml:

- [VB version (original)](https://code.google.com/p/rpttoxml/)
- [C# version](https://github.com/ajryan/RptToXml)